# Rails4 : How to display an uploaded file using association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I can upload a file and save the file name in the database using carrierwave. I'd like to display the file image on an another page using association.

( Althogh I asked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583489/rails4-how-do-i-display-and-edit-uploaded-file-using-carrierwave) pertinent to this, an additional comment couldn't prohibited. So I re-entry this as a new question. )

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
    .
    .
end
```

article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    .
    .
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
    .
    .
end
```

photo.rb

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
    validates :image, presence: true
    #validates :article_id, presence: true
end
```

.schema articles

```
CREATE TABLE "articles" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
"content" varchar(255), 
"user_id" integer, 
"created_at" datetime, 
"updated_at" datetime,);
```

.schema photos

```
CREATE TABLE "photos" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
"article_id" integer, 
"image" varchar(255), 
"created_at" datetime, 
"updated_at" datetime);
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    .
    .   
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @articles = @user.articles.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
    .
    .
end
```

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    .
    .
  def new
    @article = Article.new
    @article.photos.build
    .
    .
  end

  def create
    @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)
    .
    .
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
    .
    .
  private

    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:content, photos_attributes: [:id, :article_id, :image])
    end
    .
    .
end
```

users\show.html.erb

```
    .
    .
<div class="row">
        <%= render @articles %>
</div>
    .
    .
```

articles\ _article.html.erb

**I'd like to display the uploaded image here**

```
<li>
    .
    .
  #Please let me know how to display image here...
  <span class="content"><%= article.content %></span>
    .
    .
</li>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails4 : How do I display and edit uploaded file using carrierwave?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583489/rails4-how-do-i-display-and-edit-uploaded-file-using-carrierwave)

Comment: I guess this could work `@articles.photos.each do |photo| <%= photo.image %>`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Pavan. Although I added `<% @articles.photos.each do |photo| %>`, `<%= photo.image %>` and `<% end %>`, **NoMethodError in Users#show**, undefined method 'photos' for #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation_Article:0x4133ac0> appeared at `<% @articles.photos.each do |photo| %>`.

Comment: Thank you Pavan. I can display images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why this is such an issue. Apparently you are using Carrierwave to upload images. If you read its documentation you will find that it's pretty simple to get the image URL and display it on a page. You will need the `image_tag` to do it.

To display the image in `articles\_article.html.erb`, you can do this:

```
<li>
    .
    .
  #Please let me know how to display image here...
  <span class="content"><%= article.content %></span>

  <% article.photos.each do |photo| %>
    <span class="image"><%= image_tag(photo.image_url) if photo.image? %></span>
  <% end %>
    .
    .
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you San. I can display images. My apologies for the newbie question.